# git push error, unable to write sha1 filename ./objects

Tags: linux, git

Here is a problem.

I create a new repository with

```
mkdir -p repositories/project.git
cd repositories/project.git
git init --bare --shared=all
```

The repository is at shared local folder. UMASK is 022.

Later on, folks in my team are able to clone the project and push a few changes.
However, soon they come across this issue when they try to do 'git push'.

```
error: unable to write sha1 filename ./objects/3c/c2f933427a4215d3237a0c3b874a4ff16725: Permission denied
To myaccountname@nameofthecomputer:/repositories/project.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (unable to migrate objects to permanent storage)
error: failed to push some refs to 'myaccountname@nameofthecomputer:/repositories/project.git'
```

The problem is obviously in the way git creates some internal files/objects, because if I do:

```
sudo chmod -R 777 project.git
```

the problem is temporarily gone.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Probably a problem with umask? Can you provide the value of umask in the question?

Comment: you are using ssh as transport, right? Are you all using the same (ssh) user to push or every body is working with their own users?

Comment: everybody uses their own username, which should not be a problem, but it makes git create files with different ownership

Comment: which is why umask (and group settings for the users) becomes important because group perms have to make sense for the directories and objects that make up git's repo. that's why _resetting_ the permissions with chmod makes it work again (by the way... 777? Why? But that's another question).

Comment: Looking at the error message with more detail, I would _think_ that the gorup permissions that were set for `./objects/3c` made it impossible for other users to write in that directory..... so would need to check: umask for the owner, group for the directory and permissions. I would think that you could use `setgid` so that the group is consistent over the whole repo (a group common to all the developers that will be working there)?

Comment: I have just checked umask, it is 022

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`git init --shared=all` makes the repository *readable* by all users, but not *writable* by all users.  Making any directory writable by all users (without using the sticky bit) is generally a colossal security risk, so Git doesn't provide that as an option.

If you want people to all be able to write to a Git repository this way, then places them all in a single group, say `git`.  Change the main repository and all of its subdirectories to have that group, and make each directory setgid.  That means that each directory and file that's created will have the group `git`.  Since with `--shared=all`, Git will make all files and directories writable by that group, users should be able to push normally to the repository.

Note that the `umask` is not relevant here, since Git will adjust the permissions to honor the setting you specified.